# Ignoring width of a section/div

Tags: width, wrapper

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Html ignores the .wrapper width which is 960px. If I'm right the text inside the .wrapper div should appear in a box with a 960px width but it totally ignores the css.

jsfiddle.net/4pz89/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This will prevent browser to show content after width. You should write your text in `paragraph` to wrap the text

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4pz89/4/)

Comment: Thanks, i have to put it in a wrapper and paragraphs or only paragraphs?

Comment: I mean to say <p> your text </p> ... inside <p> tag

Comment: Oh, It's not exactly what i needed. Now it just cuts of the text, not start on a new line.

Comment: Thats what i said, use <p> tag and add some css. it will wrap your text. i have updated answer. check this out http://jsfiddle.net/4pz89/4/

Comment: When i put the text inside <p> tags it still does not wrap it to the width. Sorry for my dumb questions...

Comment: @user3519221 Updated my answer, check the link, i have added some css to wrapper class

Answer (score 0):

specify float:none; for wrapper div

Comment: It still doesn't get the width.

Comment: put whatever in one more division and give float:left or right; it will be fitted in that